# How can I increase max allowed size of packet for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pythonanywhere

I'm encountering problem with MySQL. I'm getting error `Lost connection to MySQL server during query`. On StackOverflow they say that very likely `max_allowed_packet` in MySQL config is too low.

I've tried to change it in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` but the file isn't editable. `sudo` can't be used on PA.

I'm using Sqlalchemy to handle interaction with MySQL server.

What can I do ?

**Edit:**

I've passed it into config variable:

```
class ProductionConfig:
      SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://myconnection@server$db?max_allowed_packet=32M'
```

and then passed it into app and db initialization:

```
app.config.from_object(ProductionConfig)
db.init_app(app)  #  db = Sqlalchemy()
```

output:

```
TypeError: 'max_allowed_packet' is an invalid keyword argument for connect()
```

Comment: Fix your connection string :)  there is a `$` where should be an `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem went away after I increased pool recycling:

with Sqlalchemy:

```
class Config:
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://<your-connection-string>'
    SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE = 280
```

this wasn't my idea. A member of staff at PythonAnywhere suggested it.

Comment: Nice! Good to know!

Comment: Just for clarity, if other people come across this in the future -- the error that you were getting (Lost connection to MySQL server during query) can be caused by lots of different things; the max_allowed_packet fix only applies if you're trying to insert really big things into your database (like, a megabyte or so).  The reason the PythonAnywhere staff suggested the pool_recycle fix is because the actual underlying problem was something else (server-side connection timeouts).

Answer (score 0):

You can change global variables if you have SUPER privilege. But you can't make those changes persist, so if the MySQL Server restarts, the change will revert to the original value.

```
mysql> set global max_allowed_packet=1024*1024*32;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I'm not familiar with Python Anywhere, but I would guess if you don't have permissions to edit the config file, you might not have SUPER privilege either.

The only other option is that you limit yourself to queries and results that fit in the `max_allowed_packet` that has been configured for you by the people who run Python Anywhere.

If you have need for more power, then it's time to learn to run your own server.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify this flag on **client** side and on **server** side, but the server side are the limit. You can follow **Bill Karwin** answer or try to change on client side and whatch the effects.

On client, shell:

```sh
mysql --max_allowed_packet=32M mydb -e 'SELECT * FROM table1'
```

On client, PyMySQL example:

```py
g.db = pymysql.connect(
  host               = 'localhost',
  port               = 3306,
  user               = 'user',
  password           = 'password',
  database           = 'mydb',
  max_allowed_packet = '32M'
)
```

On client, SQLAlchemy, but I'm not sure if this will work as expected:

```py
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymsql://user:pass@some_mariadb/dbname?charset=utf8mb4&max_allowed_packet=32M")
```

Comment: I'm using Sqlalchemy to handle interaction with MySQL server. Is there a way to specify `max_allowed_packet` parameter ?

Comment: Maybe with this string `mysql+pymysql://user:pass@localhost:3306/db?max_allowed_packet=32M` but I don't have sure.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I got error:  `TypeError: 'max_allowed_packet' is an invalid keyword argument for connect()` Good thinking though.

Comment: Really? Strange, worked here. Maybe you pass it outside the connection string.

Comment: Added to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: Oh... you string should be `mysql://myconnection@server/db?max_allowed_packet=32M`, and I really don't know if this will resolve your issue, by the way.